# Erratic success with @font-face in epubs

Tags: font-face, epub

I'm building epubs that I am testing in Adobe Digital Editions. The problem is that some embedded fonts will show correctly, while others will be ignored. Yet I am using the same code (e.g. below) for each font.

```
        @font-face {
            font-family : "Jura Bold Italic";
            src: url(fonts/Jura-Bold-Italic.ttf);
            font-style: normal;
    }
    h2 {
        font-family: "Jura Bold Italic";
    }
```

Some fonts that seem to display properly, others don't. Also, any other combination of quotation marks or speech marks around the font-family or src url seems to stop the @font-face working.

Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: I am having the same problem. It only happens with some fonts, and seems to be caused by bold and italic variants. If I use only the regular version of a font, it always works. Of course that means that I can't display proper italics, so that's not a solution... It works with all the `Gentium` fonts, `Linux Libertine` gives the weirdest results. There seems to be no difference between `ttf`and `otf`versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a file called "com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml"

Here's the code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <display_options>
    <platform name="*">
    <option name="specified-fonts">true</option>
    </platform>
    </display_options>
```

Create this file and save it into your META-INF folder. This should make the fonts work in iBooks and ADE.

Comment: Hi Karen, your solution seems to be aimed at Apple iBooks, whereas my problem is with Adobe Digital Editions (ADE). Or does the code you posted register in ADE as well, and fix its font display problems too?